# Where to put own properties file in an android project created with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started to use Android Studio. I don't know where to put my own properties file since there is no assets folder in the project structure.

The posted snippet works fine in eclipse, but it doesn't in Android Studio.

**Code:**

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        //load a properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("app.properties"));

        //get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("server_address"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Question 1:**
Where to put my own properties files in Android Studio (v0.5.8)?

**Question 2:**
How can I access them?

Comment: I think that by default `assets` folder is placed in `src/main/resources/assets`. If the folder does not exists try to create it and use `context.getAssets().open("app.properties")`

Comment: Salem,
Please change `context.getAssets().open("app.properties")` to `getBaseContext().getAssets().open("app.properties")` (to be more precise) and post your comment as an answer and the point is yours!

Comment: Sorry but the information I gave you is wrong. Please check my edit.

Comment: ok, no problem. it worked with the originally posted structure too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default assets folder is placed in `src/main/assets`, if it does not exists create it.

Then you can access the file using something like this:

```
getBaseContext().getAssets().open("app.properties")
```

You can find more info about Gradle Android project structure [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

Comment: If the user wants to later update his properties and save them to non-volatile storage, then loading from assets is a bad idea, since that's read only. Better to initialize properties somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

Create a subfolder in your main folder and name it assets. Place all your .properties files in this(assets) folder.

**src->main->assets->mydetails.properties**

You can access it using AssetManager class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;
private PropertyReader propertyReader;
private Context context;
private Properties properties;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    propertyReader = new PropertyReader(context);
    properties = propertyReader.getMyProperties("mydetails.properties");
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(properties.getProperty("Name"));
    Toast.makeText(context, properties.getProperty("Designation"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public class PropertyReader {

private Context context;
private Properties properties;

public PropertyReader(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    properties = new Properties();
}

public Properties getMyProperties(String file){
    try{
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(file);
        properties.load(inputStream);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }

    return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your asset subfolder in your main folder and then insert the .properties file in it.

Then, create a class to open and read the file, for example:

```
public class PropertiesReader { 

 private Context context;
 private Properties properties;
 public PropertiesReader(Context context) { 
  this.context = context;
   //creates a new object ‘Properties’
   properties = new Properties();

   public Properties getProperties(String FileName) {
   try {    
    //access to the folder ‘assets’ 
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets(); 
    //opening the file    
    InputStream inputStream = am.open(FileName); 
    //loading of the properties 
    properties.load(inputStream);
   } 
   catch (IOException e) { 
    Log.e("PropertiesReader",e.toString());
   }
  }
  return properties;
 } 
}
```

For more information, see http://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.it/2014/09/properties-file-in-android.html

Comment: the tuto is great, thanx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String getProperty(String key, Context context) throws IOException {
    try {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);
    return properties.getProperty(key);
   }catch (IOException e){
   e.fillInStackTrace();
   }
return null;
}
```

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder Structure]