# How to load .properties file data in android studio project

Tags: java, android

In my current application i need to maintain one `config.properties` file and from this properties file i need to get the data in my java file. I have placed the properties file and `ConfigUtil.java` which is accessing those properties files values are in the same location. But when i am running the application it's giving `FileNotFoundException`.

I am not able to get why this is not loading the properties file when both are inside the same folder.

My ConfigUtils.java code is :

```
public class ConfigUtil {

private Properties properties;
InputStream inputStream = null;

public Properties getUrl(){
    properties = new Properties();
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(inputStream != null){
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return properties;
}
}
```

and config.properties file is also in same folder
location of `config.properties` is :

> /app/src/main/java/config.properties

location of `ConfigUtil.java` is :

> /app/src/main/java.configutils.java

Comment: Can you post the corresponding code, please?

Comment: Get a complete short example program from below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29863387/3829818

Answer (score 47):

**Step 1**

Create a .properties file in assets folder, if you don’t have assets folder please create one under main

[image]

[image]

**config.properties**

```
name=User Name
age=User Age
ok=Click
```

**Step 2**

Create a Util.java file to read the properties file.

**Util.java**

```
package javaant.com.propertiesfile;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by Nirmal Dhara on 12-07-2015.
 */
public class Util {
    public static String getProperty(String key,Context context) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();;
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);
        return properties.getProperty(key);

    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Use variables in the properties file by calling Util.getProperty(,getApplicationContext()).

**MainActivity.java**

```
package javaant.com.propertiesfile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // read value from properties file

        TextView txtname= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        TextView txtage= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtage);
        Button btnok= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);

        try {
            txtname.setText(Util.getProperty("name",getApplicationContext()));
            txtage.setText(Util.getProperty("age",getApplicationContext()));
            btnok.setText(Util.getProperty("ok",getApplicationContext()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please download the complete code from here http://javaant.com/how-to-use-properties-file-in-android/#.VwzippN96Hs

Comment: Nice answer... :)-

Comment: The assets folder is the great insight from this answer. Thank you!

Comment: This works, but makes data inside `config.properties` vulnerable. If you decompile your .apk you will find every parameter as plain text inside. Should be used only if this content is not under secrecy.

Answer (score 0):

You should either specify the full path to the file (because the root working directory is not the directory where `ConfigUtil` is located) :

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/config.properties");
```

or use the following (which is using the directory `ConfigUtil` was loaded from):

```
inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Comment: I used both of the options but i am not getting the result. I also tried getting the path through ApplicationContext.getDir() method and it's returning the path as /data/data/package-name

Comment: @anand in case of `Android` just put it to the `res\raw` folder and later you can get `InputStream` by calling `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);`