# Android Studio write to .properties file

Tags: java, android

I followed [Where to put own properties file in an android project created with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792029/where-to-put-own-properties-file-in-an-android-project-created-with-android-stud) and I got an InputStream which reads from my .properties file successfully. However, I can't write to that .properties file, as there is no similar method to *getBaseContext().getAssets().open ("app.properties")* which returns an OutputStream. I have also read [Java Properties File appending new values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337732/java-properties-file-appending-new-values) but this didn't seem to help me, my guess is my file name for the file writer is wrong but I also tried *"assets\userInfo.properties"* which also doesn't work.

My .properties file is in src\main\assets\userInfo.properties

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        inputStream = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("userInfo.properties");
        props.load(inputStream);

        props.put("name", "smith");
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("userInfo.properties"); //this line throws error
        props.store(output, "This is overwrite file");

        String name = props.getProperty("name");
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: PROPERTIES TEST NAME CHANGE: " + name);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Current code throws this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: userInfo.properties (Read-only file system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to the assets folder, as it is inside the APK which is read-only.

Use internal or external storage instead

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to the assets folder. If you want to update your properties file, you'll have to put them some place else. If you want the initial version in the assets or raw folder, just copy it to the default files dir when the app is first used, then read from/write to it there.